# Tags that should not be used

Tags: discussion, tags

What tags should not be used in this site and why?

Comment: Tag blacklisting isn't a diamond ability, it's strictly a Dev ability.

Comment: Well, it can remain as future reference for new users :) Edited question.

Comment: Agreed, it definitely helps to point out any tags which seem out of place or will generate less usability.

Comment: Maybe we could even use the tag synonym system to let the community dynamically expand this, for example, as synonym of `[invalid-tag]` (yes, I like in system solutions)

Comment: I hope murder never makes the blacklist.

Answer (score 2):

If any of the following tags appears on the homepage (and the homepage *only*), please remove them.

- [strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strategy)
- [tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tactics)
- [subjective](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjective)
- [games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/games)
- [gameplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gameplay)
- [general-gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/general-gaming)
- [tips](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)
- [how-to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to)

Users of my pixelation mod will shortly see those tags in red.

Comment: Curious: Why are those tags bad? Esp., for example, why should one not use [strategy] for a strategy game?

Comment: @Albert http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1855/the-two-heads-of-janus-strategy-bifrons